# LuaLatex doesn't work textbf textit

Tags: luatex

The problem is that the LuaLaTeX doesn't highlight headings and numbers of sections in bold. Also doesn't works `\textbf` and '\textit'
[image]

Earlier I used pdfLaTeX and these things worked correctly. But now I have to use TTF fonts and I need to use LuaLatex now... This is my preambule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lutf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=16cm,compat=newest}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I tried to make MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{жирный}
    \textit{курсив}
    
    \textbf{bold}
    \textit{italics}
\end{document}
```

And the result is the same [image]

Comment: Please extend your code to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that can be used to reproduce your problem. Such a MWE should not only start with `\documentclass`. It also should have a `document` environment. The preamble should contain only those packages, needed to reproduce the problem. Note also, that using `fontenc` with LuaLaTeX is not recommended. LuaLaTeX uses another font encoding (see, e.g., package `fontspec` about how to use fonts with LuaLaTeX). Also using `luainputenc` should be avoided and is extremely seldom needed.

Comment: @cabohah  I updated the post, MWE has the same result

Comment: do not use fontenc, do not use luainputenc. Use fontspec to setup the fonts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use fontenc and luainputenc. This does not switch to "ttf-fonts" but uses legacy fonts.

For cyrillic, you can e.g. use newcomputermodern:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{жирный}
    \textit{курсив}
    
    \textbf{bold}
    \textit{italics}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with fontspec you can use any other font on your computer that supports cyrillic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{жирный}
    \textit{курсив}
    
    \textbf{bold}
    \textit{italics}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked in MWE but doesnt't work in other files. Look https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKkqD.png

Comment: well you are probably using a wrong font which doesn't have cyrillic. But without code nobody will be able to help you. Ask a new question with a proper MWE that shows the problem.